# automatic pulling REST API data to visualize it in Apache Superset

Tags: rest, airflow, dashboard, apache-superset

I work in a large enterprise and have a project to build some custom automated dashboards for our IT department, the small amount of data needs to be fetched only from the REST API endpoints. This process needs to be fully automated and there is not enough time to build a custom API wrapper. For this approach I was going to use Apache Airflow + Apache Superset tools. I have been googling for a couple of days for more easier open source solution than the Apache Airflow to move data from the REST API endpoints to visualize it in Superset. Please share your experience what would you choose instead of the Apache Airflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to go with fhe following solution:
Apache Airflow + PostgreSQL + Grafana (instead of a Superset, because in Grafana you can actually create a drill-down option using a workaround)